# Transforming probability distributions in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of energy values (energy represented by E) and their corresponding probability density (P(E)). I need to transform the variable such that X = |a - E|/|E|, where 'a' is a constant. I now need to get the probability density for this. I know that for two variables and distributions P(x)dx = P(y)dy but I'm having trouble coding this up. How should I transform and obtain the probability density for X, P(X)?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Is `|E|` the norm of `E`, or do you mean that every value `y` in `E` should transform to `|a - y| / |y|` ?

Comment: E is the absolute value. I have an array with many Es, so I would get many Xs

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks: I had been reading "*array of values (E)*" to mean *"an array of values, and that array is called E"*.

Comment: To get the X values, you can do something like `X_array = np.abs(a - E_array)/np.abs(E_array)`

Comment: It's not clear from your question how we're supposed to generated the probability P(X) for a given X value

Comment: Yeah, I got how to do X, I have no idea how to do P(X)

Comment: Is the energy distribution discrete or continuous?

Comment: Its continuous.